# Can't open Chrome's new window from launcher

Tags: google-chrome

I want to be able to launch a new window from the launcher.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the chrome launcher -  select 'New Window' from the list.

Edit: ( *inspired from Ken's comment* ) - There is also a shortcut for this action-

Ctrl+N.

Comment: Right, though a faster way is pressing CTRL n when in crome.